# JSONRepresentation for NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, json, nsmutabledictionary

I want to call the `JSONRepresentation` method on an `NSMutableDictionary` object.  I'm calling it using `[userDict JSONRepresentation];`, but I am getting the following warning:

```
NSMutableDictionary may not responsd to '-JSONRepresentation'
```

Could anyone tell me how to I can properly call the `JSONRepresentation` method on an object of the `NSMutableDictionary` type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Chakradhar, I'm afraid that your question is hard to understand an omits important details.  What warning are you getting?

Comment: the warning i am getting is "NSMUtableDictionary may not responsd to '-JSONRepresentation'"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `JSONRepresentation` method comes from [json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/). Include that framework in your project and import the correct headers, and you should be good to go.

Comment: sorry forgot to import "NSObject+SBJSON.h" in my file...no it is working fine for me...thanks..