# POST method of wcf sometimes dont send data on server?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have developed a web service for storing data in database from mobile application using wcf post method. Following is the method I am using to save data in database.

```
public void AddBook3(string Ans3, string Ans4, string Ans5, string Ans6, string Ans7, string Ans8, string Ans9, string Ans10, string Ans11, string Ans12,string customername)
{        
    server = "localhost";
    database = "Feed";
    uid = "root";
    string message;
    // password = "password";
    mySqlConnection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();

    mySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
            database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";";
    mySqlConnection.Open();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into answers(ans3,ans4,ans5,ans6,ans7,ans8,ans9,ans10,ans11,ans12,customername)                                             values(@ans3,@ans4,@ans5,@ans6,@ans7,@ans8,@ans9,@ans10,@ans11,@ans12,@customername)", mySqlConnection);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans3",  Ans3);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans4", Ans4);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans5", Ans5);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans6", Ans6);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans7", Ans7);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans8", Ans8);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans9", Ans9);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans10", Ans10);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans11", Ans11);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans12", Ans12);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customername", customername);
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (result == 1)
    {
        // message = userinfo.Id + "user info inserteddd";
    }
    else
    {
        //   message = userinfo.Id + "information not insertedd";
    }
}
```

Following is operation contract:

```
  [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AddBook3/{Ans3}/{Ans4}/{Ans5}/{Ans6}/{Ans7}/{Ans8}/{Ans9}/{Ans10}/{Ans11}/{Ans12}/{customername}")]
        void AddBook3(string Ans3, string Ans4, string Ans5, string Ans6, string Ans7, string Ans8, string Ans9, string Ans10, string Ans11, string Ans12, string customername);
```

And my parameters to this url is as below:

```
http://localhost:80/IBookService.svc/AddBook/Morning$(7am-11am),/Set$Top$Box$or$Chatri$Connection/3/3/3424324,234234,24234,23423,/Diya$Aur$Baati,Sapne$Suhane$Ladakpan$Ke,Jodha$Akbar,Tumhari$Pakhi,Ek$Nayi$Pehaan,Yeh$Rishsta$Kya$Kehlata$Hai,Crime$Patrol,Taarak$Mehta,Sasural$Simar$Ka,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,/Suraj-Sandhya,Jodha-Akbar,Gopi-Ahem,Ishita-$-$Raman,Rachana$-$Gunjan,Akshara$-$Naitik,/234234/rtertert/pnme
```

When I pass long string to url it won't work. When I pass just short texts then it works fine!! Why so?

Comment: Why don't you create a class to hold the Answers, and pass that? or pass a `List<string> answers` ?

Comment: @christiandev for consuming this service easily in ios app

Answer (score 1):

I would change this to something like:

```
public void AddBook3(List<string> answers ,string customername)
```

or create a class like:

```
public class CustomerAnswers
{
  public string CustomerName {get;set;}
  public string Answer1 {get;set;}
  public string Answer2 {get;set;}
  ....
}
```

and pass this class to the service.

```
public void AddBook3(CustomerAnswers customerAnswers)
```

I think the issue you are getting is the limitation on URL length, which I think is **~2000** characters. See this SO post [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

**EDIT**: Based on Objective-c comment

I'm not familiar with Objective-c, but I'm assuming you'd create a **JSON** object that represents the `CustomerAnswers` class, and pass this...there's an example question here [Pass object as a parameter to wcf service in Objective C on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328824/pass-object-as-a-parameter-to-wcf-service-in-objective-c-on-ios).

Comment: i would also like to to do like this but how can i consume this method in ios phone app in Objective c

Comment: I have added an edit to the answer, which has a link on how to post json objects to WCF.